# Apex Batch Job fails if I create and delete a ContentVersion

Tags: apex, batch, contentversion, contentdocument

I just found a strange Salesforce behavior (maybe, an internal defect). If a code tries to insert a new ContentVersion and then delete it (via ContentDocument) within a single APEX transaction (the execute() method), then a batch fails right after the next iteration started.

This is a sample class that helps to reproduce the defect (note that your org must have at least 2 accounts):

```
public class TestBatchJob implements Database.Batchable<SObject>
{
    //
    //Implemetation of the Database.Batchable interface
    //
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator('Select Id From Account limit 2');
    }

    private Integer iteration = 0;
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Account[] scope)
    {
        System.debug('***** ' + this.iteration);
        this.iteration++;

        //- create a test file
        ContentVersion file = new ContentVersion();
        file.Title = 'QWERTY';
        file.Origin = 'H';
        file.PathOnClient = 'path';
        file.VersionData = Blob.valueOf('EMPTY_STRING');
        insert file;

        //- re-read the file to take its ContentDocumentId and delete the document
        file = [Select Id, ContentDocumentId From ContentVersion Where Id = :file.Id];
        delete (new ContentDocument(Id = file.ContentDocumentId));
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {}
    //
}
```

Use this line to put the job in a queue:

```
Database.executeBatch(new TestBatchJob(), 1);
```

As a result, in the developer console you should see "Internal Salesforce.com Error" text near the log for the 2nd iteration.
It is interesting that the issue is not reproduced with batches which do not use query locator in the start() method.

Does anybody know why this is happening (as of now, it looks like a SF defect to me)?

Comment: well, since by definition an 'Internal Salesforce Error' is a gack and gacks shouldnt happen; I'd agree it was a defect. To work around, did you try using a savepoint-rollback instead of deleting the `ContentDocument`? (I haven't tried this)

Comment: @cropredy, I tried a savepoint-rollback (just for fun) and didn't get this issue. But this is not useful in real code. I provided simple example of a batch job that does not have any business meaning just to simplify your testing. Real batch job makes some useful work between insert and delete and this work should not be undone.
If it's a gack, I hope SF team will find this question :)

Answer (score 1):

It is hit-or-miss whether SFDC will see your report here on the gack but they do monitor gacks through a sophisticated surveillance system that is described in this [developer article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html) by Josh Kaplan.

If you have Premier Support, you should file a case. If not, someone on this forum may file one on your behalf. I didn't see any obvious Known Issue relating to this but I may have missed it (and there are some Known Issues not searchable)

Waiting for SFDC to fix this could extend into infinity or it might get fixed in the next patch. Hard to say.  Hence, filing a case.

As for workarounds

- I had suggested using `SavePoint - Rollback` but your comment thread said that there was intermediate work that needed to be preserved. Hence ...
- Defer the deletion of the `ContentDocument` to the  batch `finish()` method by keeping a list of such Ids either in the batch object's stateful variables or persist to a custom object within each `execute()`. Be mindful of heap size for the stateful variables

Comment: Hi @cropredy. Thank you for your answer. Yes, I read this article before posting my question here, found the "Help Me Help You" section where the author says "post your experience on Stack Exchange" and decided to describe my problem here just to "help them help me" :) (I don't have Premier Support).

Comment: Regarding the workarounds, the 2nd one is good (if we can use such a word for any workaround at all), at least I implemented it in my batch job before to post a question. It makes the code more complicated and forces us to hope that the finish() method will always be executed correctly (if an admin kills the job or exception occurs before the deletion then files will not be deleted). But I didn't find a better workaround. And that's great that we're thinking similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up-- 5 years later, this is still an issue.  We have a Batch Apex operation that involves creating/deleting different ContentVersions in the same Execute trigger context, and the second a delete happens in an Execute method (which doesn't always happen), any future runs of the Execute method fail with an "Internal Salesforce.com Error" (this error appears to trigger one time, even if there are multiple potential batches that would be iterated over).

I think we're going to refactor our batch to queue the deletes to happen 1x during the Finish method... it's clear there isn't a fix happening anytime soon!